# plot subset of data in facet time series in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting monthly faceted time series, the facet plots only the dataset for the respective month but the x-axis shows the entire time series for the whole year. Resulting in very compressed facet plots.

Here is the complete code to replicate the problem:

```
library(chron)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

t1 <- chron("1/1/2011", "00:00:00", )
t2 <- chron("12/31/2011", "00:00:01") # 1 sec is to counter floating point errors
DateTime <- seq(t1, t2, by = times("06:00:00"))
GHI <- sample(0:1000, 1457, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(DateTime = as.POSIXct (DateTime), GHI)
# Upto now df represents my actual dataset. Month column is extracted from the DateTime    column.

df$Month <- format(df$DateTime, "%m")

ggplot(df, aes(DateTime, GHI)) + 
       geom_line() + 
       scale_x_datetime(breaks = '10 days', labels = date_format("%d")) + 
       xlab("") + 
       facet_grid(. ~ Month)
```

As you can see the facet should show the data AND scale for the respective month. But it shows the scale of the entire year and plots for the month only.

Another question is that for facet I had to create a month column. Is there a way I don't have to do that since that information is already available in the DateTime column

Comment: Why did you remove my edit? Your code doesn't run. Just try to paste it in the console. Anyway: `facet_grid(. ~ Month, scales = "free_x")`

Comment: That works. thanks. i didn't remove your edit. I was editing it myself that could be the issue